# qmake и несколько целей

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

здравствуйте, есть проект такой структуры:
хочу чтоб при сборке qmake main.pro && make собирались подпроекты сервера и клиента:

```
app /
    main.pro          <---главный .pro-file
    common /
        file.cpp
        file.h
    server /
        server.pro    <--- .pro-file сервера
        main.cpp
    client /
        client.pro    <--- .pro-file клиента
        main.cpp
```

в main.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += console c++11  
CONFIG -= qt

SUBDIRS = client server common

client.file = client.pro
server.file = server.pro
```

в server.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = server
CONFIG += console c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    ../common/file.cpp

HEADERS += \
    ../common/file.h

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

LIBS += \
       -lIce \
       -lIceUtil \
       -lpthread
```

в client.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = client
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    ../common/file.cpp

HEADERS += \
    ../common/file.h

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17

LIBS += \
       -lIce \
       -lIceUtil \
       -lpthread
```

в итоге при сборке main проекта получаются ошибки... подскажите как правильно

Comment: можно текст ошибки? возможно, связано с тем, что common в **subdirs** указано, а файла **.pro** в этом каталоге нет.

Comment: Cannot find file: /home/tree_js/projects_cpp/Qt/ice_example/ice_example/client.pro

Comment: Попробуйте указать полный путь в **main.pro**:``client.file = client/client.pro
server.file = server/server.pro``

Comment: @LXA, ок, вечером попробую, спасибо за ответ

Comment: @LXA, да, в этом дело и было... спасибо